# Unity: Adding a blank element to an array of SerializedProperty's

Tags: c#, arrays, user-interface, unity-game-engine, serialization

I'm trying to create a class for drawing an array of arbitrary serialized objects in the Unity Inspector. I can draw them just fine, but at the end of the function I want to have a button to add an empty element to the array. Most advice I can find online says to simply use arraySize++, but this copies the last element of the array which is not the desired behaviour. What I have so far is:

```
public static void ShowArray(SerializedProperty arr, Type elemType)
{
    //Draw array elements

    if (GUILayout.Button("ADD EMPTY ELEMENT")) 
    {
        arr.arraySize += 1;
        SerializedProperty prop = arr.GetArrayElementAtIndex (arr.arraySize - 1);
        prop.isExpanded = true;
        UnityEngine.Object nextObj = Activator.CreateInstance (elemType) as UnityEngine.Object;
        prop.objectReferenceValue = nextObj;
    }
}
```

However this fails on the line:

```
prop.objectReferenceValue = nextObj;
```

with the error: type is not a supported pptr value

This may be because the element type derives from System.Object and not UnityEngine.Object, but I'm not sure how to get around that problem? It is obvious that Unity is able to serialize and draw serialized objects that derive from System.Object because the entire array is filled with elements of that same type, but how can I construct and append a new one?

Answer (score 0):

May be a little bit late :) but there actually is a workaround for this. I assume you're trying to do this in Editor script. So you can reach actual target like:

```
YourType trg { get { return target as YourType; } }
```

And use this reference when you add a new item to your collection. Let's say you have an array. So simply you can do this:

```
if (GUILayout.Button("ADD EMPTY ELEMENT")) 
{
    arr.InsertArrayElementAtIndex(arr.arraySize);
    //arr is your actual Serializable Array field
    trg.arr[trg.arr.Length - 1] = new YourType() { isExpanded = true };
}
```